# Android get notification when a person enters or exits a region

Tags: android, android-geofence

I am new to Android and developing a background service that would track whether the person is inside or outside of certain radius of an area (fixed lat/long coordinates).

Battery is critical and I don't need actual location (coarse location). It is fine if the event is delivered few minutes after the actual entry/exit as I need just one notification for entry and one for exit

I don't want alarm manager to trigger every 10 minutes to check current location as this would drain battery.
Is there a way to achieve this with minimal battery drain and preferably without having the user to turn on GPS (consumes battery)?

Answer (score 1):

Look like you can build a GeoFence and send notification on GeoFence transition. Please see this documentation:
https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

Answer (score 0):

It is called Geofencing. There is [good article](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html) on Developers site. But it requires GPS (FINE_LOCATION).

Another solution: implement own Geofence-like "framework", but using network data (COARSE_LOCATION), not GPS. Yes, it requires periodical polling of location. A way to decrease battery drain is to poll less frequently. Also you can use [location updates listener](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html) with a low priority.

Comment: Thanks Sergey for your response. I was going through [location updates listener](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html). Will the location callback work in background service or do I need to take wake lock. Also, it appears that last know location would serve my purpose but I didn't find any document on when it is updated (interval of location update)?

Comment: @user2107373 Sorry, I never worked with it, so I don't know details.